# Basic complex numbers inequality problem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

The statement I want to prove goes as follow:

$|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}|<1$ if $|a|<1$ or $|b|<1$

I have already proved that since $|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}|=1$ if $|a|=1$ or $|b|=1$ and the proof goes as follow

without loss of generality suppose $|a|=1$ then $|\bar{a}|=1 $ so $a\bar{a}=1$ so we have $|a-b|=|a-b||\bar{a}|=|a\bar{a}-\bar{a}b|=|1-\bar{a}b|$ proving what we want.

So , is there any alike idea to prove that $|a-b|<|1-\bar{a}b|$ if $|a|<1$ or $|b|<1$??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: Take $a=3/2$ and $b=1/2$.

The correct statement here is that the given quantity is less than $1$ if and only both $|a|$ and $|b|$ are bigger than $1$ or smaller than $1$. The proof of that goes as follows: \begin{align}|a-b|< |1-\bar{a} b| &\iff |a-b|^2< |1-\bar{a}b|^2 \\ &\iff |a|^2 -2 \;Re(\bar{a}b) +|b|^2< 1 - 2 \;Re(\bar{a}b) +|a|^2|b|^2 \\ & \iff |a|^2 + |b|^2< 1+ |a|^2|b|^2 \\ & \iff (|a|^2-1)(|b|^2-1)>0 \\ & \iff (|a|-1)(|b|-1)>0\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For $|a|=\sqrt{a\overline{a}}<1$ and the same for $b$ it holds

$$|a-b|<|a-b||\overline{a}|=|a\overline{a}-\overline{a}b|<|\sqrt{a\overline{a}}-\overline{a}b|<|1-\overline{a}b|.$$

First step: we use $|a|=|\overline{a}|<1$.

Second step: we use $|xy|=|x||y|$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$.

Third step: we use $x<\sqrt{x}$ for $x\in(0,1)$.

Fourth step: we use $\sqrt{a\overline{a}}<1$.

Comment: No, there is no reason for those inequalities to be true. Your third and fourth steps are not correctly justified at all.

Comment: I see your point. Thinking about it, I will.