# Prove that $|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}|<1$ if $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$.

Tags: inequality

Prove that $$|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}|<1$$ if $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$.

After doing some calculation I ended up in a dead end

$$|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}|=\sqrt{\frac{|a|^2+|b|^2-(a\bar{b}+b\bar{a})}{1+|a|^2|b|^2-(a\bar{b}+b\bar{a})}}$$

How do I proceed further ?

Is there any alternating ways like using cauchy's inequality ?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506058/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1699090/42969.

Comment: These (and more related questions) are found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7C%5Cfrac%7Ba-b%7D%7B1-%5Cbar%7Ba%7Db%7D%7C%3C1%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the inequality as follows:

$$(a-b)^2<(1-ab)^2 \Rightarrow a^2-2ab+b^2-1+2ab-(ab)^2<0$$

This transforms to: $(a^2-1)(b^2-1)>0$ or $(1-a^2)(1-b^2)>0$, which is clearly true.

Comment: The usage of $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ indicates that $a$ and $b$ are *complex numbers* and those cannot be compared with $<$.